# How to get raw binary data from a POST request processed by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, curl, binary-data

I need to write an application which would be able to process binary data sent by CUrl, such as:

```
curl localhost:8080/data --data-binary @ZYSF15A46K1.txt
```

I've created a POST processing method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/data")
    public void acceptData(HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity) throws Exception {
        process(requestEntity.getBody());
    }
```

However it doesn't seem to be returning raw binary data. I've tried sending a GZip file and after going through Spring it is now longer decompressible, which leads me to believe I'm either getting too much data or too little data.

How do I solve this issue and get raw binary data?

Comment: Try to use `HttpServletDequest` as the input parameter of your controller and read raw data from it's `InputStream`.

Comment: @GeminiKeith tried that as well, it's always returning an empty object for some reason.

Comment: have you ever set the character encoding? You can check the `Content-Length` to make sure you get the right request. If `Content-Length` valid, you can read it from `InputStream` with specific length. If not please check your request.

Comment: @GeminiKeith Thank you! I looked a bit more into HttpServletRequest and the issue was solved (see my answer).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's as easy as declaring an InputStream in your controller method's parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/data")
public void acceptData(InputStream dataStream) throws Exception {
    processText(dataStream);
}
```

You shouldn't need to disable HiddenHttpMethodFilter, if you do it's probably that your request is wrong in some way. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5676.

Comment: "wrong in some way" = check that `Content-Type` header is set in request and that it is not `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-url-encoded`

Comment: what annotation shall I use to get binary data from postman to spring boot?

Comment: it depends on how you send it with postman. See this https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#sending-body-data. If you send "raw" data, you can use the declaration above as-is.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to resolve this using the following code:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/data")
public void acceptData(HttpServletRequest requestEntity) throws Exception {
    byte[] processedText = IOUtils.toByteArray(requestEntity.getInputStream());
    processText(processedText);
}
```

Spring does pre-processing by default, which causes the `HttpServletRequest` to be empty by the time it reaches the `RequestMapping`. Adding the `FilterRegistrationBean` Bean solves that issue.

Comment: Yes, I've forgot that. Input Stream default can only be read once.

Comment: My hunch is that funky HiddenHttpMethodFilter disable is to turn off auto multipart filtering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32790327/32453