# Disable spring boot multipart upload by controller

Tags: spring, file, file-upload, spring-boot, multipart

I am using spring boot for uploading files. The files sizes are usually about 2GB and we cannot use the default spring boot `StandardServletMultipartResolver` or `CommonsMultipartResolver` since the server have limited resource (disk space) or memory for buffering. So we would like to get the file inputsteam and store the file directly to the cloud storage.

I know spring boot has the `multipart.enabled` property so I can set it to false to skip the spring `MultipartResolver`. But this disables multipart globally. Does any one know if there is a way to disable multipart by controller/method?

Comment: You either enable it or disable it you cannot have both. Unless you define 2 separate `DispatcherServlet`s one with multipart and one without. The easiest is to just disable it and handle file uploads yourself. You can probably create a helper class to make it easier.

Answer (score 8):

If you enable `resolve-lazily`, the result is exactly what I think you're asking for.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = true
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily = true
```

Now you can write controllers with either form of signature.

Pre-parsing by the built-in multipart resolver...

```
@PostMapping("/upload1")
public ResponseEntity<Void> postUpload1(
    @RequestParam("metadata") MultipartFile metadata,
    @RequestParam("payload") MultipartFile payload)
```

Or post-parsing (which you can parse yourself)...

```
@PostMapping(path = "/upload2", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> postUpload2(HttpServletRequest rawRequest)
```

Comment: spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = true, postUpload2 not work

Comment: Although this proposed answer looks good, I had no success in running MultiPart and non-Multipart based Controllers at the same time, because there is only one DispatcherServlet. and the config is mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is quite old yet, but here is a working solution (Spring Boot 2):

application.properties:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
```

config:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver customMultipartResolver() {
  final CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
  multipartResolver.setResolveLazily(true);
  return multipartResolver;
}
```

Controller (manual handling):

```
  @PostMapping(consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
  public ResponseEntity<> manualHandling(
      HttpServletRequest request) throws FileUploadException, IOException {

    final FileItemIterator iterStream = new ServletFileUpload().getItemIterator(request);

    ...
  }
```

Controller (standard multipart):

```
  @PostMapping(value = "file", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
  public ResponseEntity<> multipartHandling(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    final Map<String, MultipartFile> files = request.getMultiFileMap().toSingleValueMap();

    Iterator<MultipartFile> iter =files.values().iterator();

    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to conditionally disable multipary with a custom MultipartResolver, but you should do it at request level.

With multipart enabled, the files are stored locally on the server, and with multipart off, your controller has to do the parsing manually.

Since I read so much conflicting information on this topic, I decided to go into the details here https://youtu.be/OpJ0jKRBa1g where I illustrate how to have both strategies coexist at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

This shows how it can be done :

[springboot-large-streaming-file-upload-using-apache-commons-fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782026/springboot-large-streaming-file-upload-using-apache-commons-fileupload)

Look at the answer of [balajeerc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953125/balajeerc)

Comment: The parent comment mentions they're aware of this approach, but are looking for something that doesn't disable multipart globally.