# Delegating HTTP request handling from a Spring MVC Controller to Jersey 2

Tags: spring-mvc, post, jax-rs, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to plug my set of RESTful endpoints (which rely on *Jersey 2* JAX-RS implementation) into a 3rd party *Spring MVC* web application running on top of *Tomcat* 9.

I'm not allowed to modify `web.xml`, nor is my plug-in available when the container starts, so [annotation-based configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/java-web-app-without-web-xml) is not an option, either. This means I can't deploy *Jersey*'s [`ServletContainer`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html) directly.

What I *am* allowed is plugging into *Spring MVC*, namely

1. creating a custom partial *Spring* application context and
2. implementing a custom [`Controller`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html), so I have written this naïve implementation which is actually close to the standard [`ServletWrappingController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html):

```
package com.example

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.Collections
import java.util.Enumeration
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig
import javax.servlet.ServletContext
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

class JerseyServletInitializer(servletContext: ServletContext,
                               componentClasses: List<Class<*>>,
                               components: List<Any>): AbstractController() {
    private val servletContainer: ServletContainer

    init {
        val resourceConfig = ResourceConfig()
            .apply {
                // Register org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
                componentClasses.forEach { clazz ->
                    register(clazz)
                }
                // Register REST endpoints
                components.forEach { component ->
                    register(component)
                }
            }

        // Provide a dummy ServletConfig
        val servletConfig = object : ServletConfig {
            override fun getInitParameter(name: String): String? = null

            override fun getInitParameterNames(): Enumeration<String> = emptyList<String>().let {
                Collections.enumeration(it)
            }

            override fun getServletName(): String = ServletContainer::class.java.name

            override fun getServletContext(): ServletContext = servletContext
        }

        // Create and initialize Jersey's ServletContainer
        servletContainer = ServletContainer(resourceConfig).apply {
            init(servletConfig)
        }

        setSupportedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS")
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun handleRequestInternal(request: HttpServletRequest,
                                       response: HttpServletResponse): ModelAndView? {
        // Delegate all HTTP requests to Jersey
        servletContainer.service(request, response)
        return null
    }
}
```

The above works fine with the only exception of file upload scenario (i. e. `HTTP POST` with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`).

*Spring* detects such requests and converts a regular `HttpServletRequest` into a [`MultipartHttpServletRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html), reading out and exhausting its input stream (`mark()`/`reset()` are not supported). The web application has a custom [`MultipartResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html) which I can't affect in any way:

```xml
  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

This means *Jersey* receives a multipart `HTTP POST` with an empty request body, throws a [`MIMEParsingException`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull/1.9.12/org.jvnet.mimepull/org/jvnet/mimepull/MIMEParsingException.html) and responds with `HTTP 400 Bad Request`.

As far as I understand, multipart resolution can only be disabled globally, and not on a per-controller basis ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133381), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234757), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870989)).

**Questions:**

1. What is the best way to work the `MultipartResolver` around, so that *Jersey* receives an non-modified request?
2. Alternatively, can you recommend an API to re-construct the request body (i. e. do the opposite of what `MultipartResolver` does and feed the new `HttpServletRequest` to *Jersey*)? This can, of course, be done by hand, but I'd rather rely on the existing libraries.