# Why spring http multipart disabling is not working

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to disable the

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=false
```

in my yaml but it is not working

look at my yaml

```
spring:
  http:
   multipart:
    enabled: false
server:
  servlet:
   context-path: /content
  port: 9080
```

Just wondering why it is not working, because I want to use Apache `commons-fileupload` to implement file upload process (because it can fetch data directly from request) and in spring boot multipart it stores files temp in memory then process the data from file.. I am trying to disable it, but it is not working and the strange part this port config and context path `/content` works fine , then why it is not.

Please provide some valuable suggestion what could be wrong here.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Boot 2 you should use this property:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
```

See [Disable spring boot multipart upload by controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133381/disable-spring-boot-multipart-upload-by-controller)