# Spring upload non multipart file as a stream

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-boot, binaryfiles

I am working with Spring Boot 1.2.5 and I would like to upload a raw binary file to a controller. The file size may be large so I do not want to hold the whole request in memory but instead stream the file, in fact the file is being generated as transmission start so the client doesn't even know the size of the file. I see an example of how to do something similar with a multipart encoded file upload [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782026/springboot-large-streaming-file-upload-using-apache-commons-fileupload). However, I do not want a multipart encoded upload, just a raw stream of bytes. I can't seem to find a way to handle this use-case in spring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just consume the `HttpServletRequest` inputstream.
Just be aware that if you have any filters that pre process the request and consume the inputstream then this might not work.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(path="fileupload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void fileUpload(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(request.getInputStream(), Paths.get("myfilename"));
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this handler is called while the upload is still in progress. Meaning no data is being stored in a temp file and the whole file is not already in memory at the time of invocation, correct?

Comment: @cmaynard The method is entered once the request header is processed. You then get a stream of the request body. It is possible that you might have a servlet filter that uses something like `TeeInputStream` to keep its own buffer of the request body, but in a default spring-boot, spring-mvc project you shouldn't have anything like that.

Answer (score 11):

I want to share some small discoveries that might help someone.

I was using spring's `MultipartFile` to upload large files and was concerned that spring would store the contents in memory. So, I decided to use the `getInputStream()` method, hoping that this would stream the file directly to the desired location:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(new File("/storage/upload/", file.getOriginalFilename())));

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Saved");
}
```

When I tested the controller with a 2GB file, it was taking a long time to hit the controller method. So I debugged and found out that spring/Tomcat first stores the file in a temporary folder before handling it to the controller. This means that, when you call `getInputStream()` it returns a `FileInputStream` pointing to the file stored on filesystem instead of streaming directly from the client browser.

In another words, calling `FileCopyUtils.copy()` is slow, because it copies the entire file to another location and then delete the temporary file, making it take twice the time to complete the request.

I investigated and discovered that you can disable the spring features and handle the multipart requests manually, but is kind complicated and error prone. So, digging a little more, I found out that the `MultipartFile` has a method called `transferTo` that actually moves the temporary file to the desired location. I tested it and it was instantaneous. My code got like this:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    file.transferTo(new File("/storage/upload/", file.getOriginalFilename()));

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Saved");
}
```

Conclusion, if all you want is to upload the file to a specific directory/file you can just use this solution and it will be as fast as streaming the file manually.

**IMPORTANT:** there are two `transferTo()` methods, one that receives a `Path` and another one that receives a `File`. Don't use the one that receives a `Path` because it will copy the file and be slow.

**EDIT1:**

I tested the solution using the `HttpServletRequest`, but it will still store a temporary file unless you set the spring config `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = false`. The same occurs for solutions using `MultipartHttpServletRequest`.

I see three main benefits using the solution I found:

1. It's simple
2. It allows you to handle several files at once, you just need to add multiple `@RequestPart MultipartFile` to your controller method
3. It allows you to easily process a response body with the files

```
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestPart @Valid MyCustomPOJO pojo, @RequestPart MultipartFile file1, @RequestPart MultipartFile file2, @RequestPart MultipartFile file3)
```

Here is the URL for a test project that I've created to test some concepts, including this one:

https://github.com/noschang/SpringTester

Comment: Well although your research is interesting and has value - its not related to the topic at hand about streaming uploads / non-multiparts

Comment: Thanks for such an answer. Can I use the input stream of multipart file without saving the whole file anywhere?

Comment: Isn't there still the problem that when you are using MultipartFile, spring will store the file to memory for a while in the controller?

Comment: "Don't use the one that receives a Path because it will copy the file and be slow." Looking at the source, it looks like they would take the same time, as they both use FileCopyUtils.copy

Answer (score 2):

To upload large files that don't block your MVC request thread pool or use up more memory than you have in your JVM you can use a combination of accepting the `HttpServletRequest` (or an `InputStream`) and then receiving it efficiently using NIO within a `CompletableFuture`.

Here's a sample controller to get you started. Before using this in a real scenario you will want to make sure that any filename that you write to is strongly validated before you do it.

```java
@RestController
public class TestService {

  @PostMapping("/upload/{filename:.+}")
  public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> upload(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("filename") String filename)
      throws ServiceUnavailableException, NotFoundException {

    final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 128;

    // TODO: validate 'filename' to ensure it's legal and will be written where you want it
    // to be within the file system. Watch out for the many security gotchas.

    // asynchronously accept the upload

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

      try {

        // TODO: Change this to where you want the file to be written
        Path file = Paths.get(filename);

        try (ReadableByteChannel inChannel = Channels.newChannel(request.getInputStream())) {
          try (WritableByteChannel outChannel = Files.newByteChannel(file, CREATE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, WRITE)) {

            // no way to free a ByteBuffer manually - GC does it
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            while (inChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
              buffer.flip();
              outChannel.write(buffer);
              buffer.compact();
            }

            // EOF will leave buffer in fill state, flip it and write anything remaining

            buffer.flip();

            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
              outChannel.write(buffer);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        // TODO: log the exception because spring doesn't seem to do that
        throw new ResponseStatusException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Failed to upload the file", ex);
      }

      // upload completed successfully

      return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not tested your solution but it deserve more attention, I have one question, how do  you manage multiple parameter beside the file in upload from request.getInputStream()?It seems here that you are sure to find the uploaded file in the data contained in the InputStream and I don't get this step, what if I send for example fileName, findSize and the binaries, how do you read the parameters?