# Uploading Large Files With Springboot with additional data [HttpServlet]

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, servlets, form-data

I am trying to upload big files with additional data for my upload using form-data and received it on the server side by using HttpServerletRequest.

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append("file", files[0])
data.append("project", "123")
data.append("userId", 1)
```

Was able to upload big files by using this solution [SpringBoot: Large Streaming File Upload Using Apache Commons FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782026/springboot-large-streaming-file-upload-using-apache-commons-fileupload)

But the problem is it is missing some of the parameters I needed to proceed on the operation

it was returning null, specifically after adding 
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false

When I try this:

```java
 String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
 String project = request.getParameter("project");
```

I was getting a null. Is there any solution for this?