# Receive HTTP Stream in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-headers, http-streaming

i want to receive a HTTP Stream in SpringBoot but the InputStream of HttpServletRequest seems not to be an endless HTTP Stream and only contains the Content of first HTTP Body.

I want to process a chuncked HTTP Stream in SpringBoot on which is puhed some Value String from time to time.

Currently I tried something like this in a controller:

```
  @Override
    public void  test(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("StreamStart");
        try {



            byte[] buffer = new  byte[1024];
            while(true){
                int len = request.getInputStream().read(buffer);
                 if(len!=-1) {
                     System.out.println("Len: " + len);
                     System.out.println(new String(buffer));
                 }
                 Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x){
            x.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("StreamEnd");

    }
```

However the first Request Body after the header works, but the second does not appear in my Controller.

Does SpringBoot cancles the connection or the stream? 
Can I have access to the complete HTTP Input stream to get my values from it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Multipart request would be usefull for you?
That way you can recieve multiple parts of data
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html
Example:

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadStream(@RequestParam MultipartFile[] multipartFiles){
    for(MultipartFile multipartFile:multipartFiles){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: nice idea, bit does multipart need a predifined content lengh? i need some streaming without a predefined content lengh because the client is pushing data to the server via HTTP Streaming and i can't know the content lengh

Comment: I want to relize a endless streaming between Server and Client, i don't think it's possible with multipart.

Comment: I used it already as streaming from client to server, here is good description how to do it. For content length you can set properties to large value. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782026/springboot-large-streaming-file-upload-using-apache-commons-fileupload

Comment: Thanks but can I modify HTTP Header content len to a big number and then it will work as streaming? I cant imagine that

Comment: No, not that way. You need a server that reads multipart streaming and you client that send it. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/MultipartStream.html for server part

Comment: ok, i think that multipart streaming is for files but not for content with a undefined content len